# Getting undefined variable error when using msoEncodingUTF8 in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

What do I need to do to avoid getting an undefined variable error when using the msoEncodingUTF8 enumerated value? This is in a VBA script attached to a MS Access form to output a report to a file:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub DoStuff()
    ...    
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "myReport", acFormatPDF, "C:/path/file.pdf",False,"",msoEncodingUTF8, 0
    ...
End Sub
```

I know I could replace the msoEncodingUTF8 with 65001 and just move on but I'd really rather use the enumerated value for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*msoEncodingUTF8* is a member of the *Office.MsoEncoding* enum.  You can make it available by setting a reference to your version of *Microsoft Office  Object Library*.

In general, constants whose names start with *mso* are available from that library.  I'm not certain that is always the case, but I'd look there first.

If you prefer to limit the number of references in your project, you could just define that constant locally.

```vb
Const msoEncodingUTF8 As Long = 65001
```

Comment: Thankyou! I had included the Microsoft Office Object but wasn't prepending the msoEncodingUTF8 with the right namespacing - so adding Office.MsoEncoding out the front of msoEncodingUTF8 did the trick. In fact once I had the Office. down the autocomplete tool started offering up suggestions. Its always the little things!